flutter use build_runner output Configuring *** in target *** but this is not a known Builder
When I try to generate a database management file using annotations and build_runner in Flutter, the output is look like:
➜  tao_bao flutter pub run build_runner build                                                 
Deprecated. Use `dart run` instead.
Building package executable... 
Built build_runner:build_runner.
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 129ms
[WARNING] Configuring `database_generator:database_generator` in target `tao_bao:tao_bao` but this is not a known Builder
[WARNING] Throwing away cached asset graph because the build phases have changed. This most commonly would happen as a result of adding a new dependency or updating your dependencies.
[WARNING] Throwing away cached asset graph because the language version of some package(s) changed. This would most commonly happen when updating dependencies or changing your min sdk constraint.
[INFO] Cleaning up outputs from previous builds. completed, took 3ms
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 27ms
[WARNING] Invalidated precompiled build script due to missing asset graph.
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 311ms
[WARNING] Configuring `database_generator:database_generator` in target `tao_bao:tao_bao` but this is not a known Builder
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 515ms
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 0ms
[INFO] Running build completed, took 2ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 26ms
[INFO] Succeeded after 31ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)


The file directory structure is as follows
➜  tao_bao tree
.
├── README.md
├── analysis_options.yaml
├── build.yaml
│ 
├── lib
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── database_annotations.dart
│   │   ├── database_generator.dart
│   │   ├── database_helper.dart
│   │   ├── user_dao.dart
│   │   └── user_model.dart
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── Image00001.webp
│   │   ├── Image00002.webp
│   │   ├── Image00004.webp
│   │   ├── Image00005.webp
│   │   ├── splash.webp
│   │   └── Logo-1.png
│   ├── main.dart
│   ├── model
│   └── pages
│       ├── index_page.dart
│       └── intro_page.dart
│ 
├── pubspec.lock
├── pubspec.yaml
├── tao_bao.iml
└── test
    └── widget_test.dart


Here is the Generator:
import 'package:build/build.dart';
import 'package:source_gen/source_gen.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart';
import 'database_annotations.dart';

Builder databaseBuilder(BuilderOptions options) =>
    SharedPartBuilder([DatabaseGenerator()], 'database_generator');

class DatabaseGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<Table> {
  @override
  String generateForAnnotatedElement(
      Element element, ConstantReader annotation, BuildStep buildStep) {
    if (element is ClassElement) {
      final className = element.name;
      final tableName = annotation.read('name').stringValue;

      final buffer = StringBuffer();
      buffer.writeln('class ${className}Dao {');
      buffer.writeln('  final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper();');
      buffer.writeln('  final String tableName = \'$tableName\';');

      for (var method in element.methods) {
        if (method.metadata.any((meta) => meta.element?.enclosingElement?.name == 'Insert')) {
          final insertAnnotation = method.metadata
              .firstWhere((meta) => meta.element?.enclosingElement?.name == 'Insert');
          final table = ConstantReader(insertAnnotation.computeConstantValue())
              .read('table')
              .stringValue;

          buffer.writeln(generateInsertMethod(method, table));
        }

        if (method.metadata.any((meta) => meta.element?.enclosingElement?.name == 'Query')) {
          final queryAnnotation = method.metadata
              .firstWhere((meta) => meta.element?.enclosingElement?.name == 'Query');
          final sql = ConstantReader(queryAnnotation.computeConstantValue())
              .read('sql')
              .stringValue;

          buffer.writeln(generateQueryMethod(method, sql));
        }

        if (method.metadata.any((meta) => meta.element?.enclosingElement?.name == 'Update')) {
          final updateAnnotation = method.metadata
              .firstWhere((meta) => meta.element?.enclosingElement?.name == 'Update');
          final sql = ConstantReader(updateAnnotation.computeConstantValue())
              .read('sql')
              .stringValue;

          buffer.writeln(generateUpdateMethod(method, sql));
        }

        if (method.metadata.any((meta) => meta.element?.enclosingElement?.name == 'Delete')) {
          final deleteAnnotation = method.metadata
              .firstWhere((meta) => meta.element?.enclosingElement?.name == 'Delete');
          final sql = ConstantReader(deleteAnnotation.computeConstantValue())
              .read('sql')
              .stringValue;

          buffer.writeln(generateDeleteMethod(method, sql));
        }
      }

      buffer.writeln('}');
      return buffer.toString();
    }

    return '';
  }

  String generateInsertMethod(MethodElement element, String table) {
    final params = element.parameters.map((param) => '\'${param.name}\': ${param.name}').join(', ');

    return '''
    Future<void> ${element.name}(${element.parameters.map((p) => '${p.type} ${p.name}').join(', ')}) async {
      final db = await dbHelper.database;
      await db.insert('$table', {$params});
    }
    ''';
  }

  String generateQueryMethod(MethodElement element, String sql) {
    final returnType = element.returnType;
    return '''
    Future<$returnType> ${element.name}() async {
      final db = await dbHelper.database;
      final result = await db.rawQuery('$sql');
      if (result.isNotEmpty) {
        return $returnType.fromMap(result.first);
      }
      return null;
    }
    ''';
  }

  String generateUpdateMethod(MethodElement element, String sql) {
    return '''
    Future<void> ${element.name}(${element.parameters.map((p) => '${p.type} ${p.name}').join(', ')}) async {
      final db = await dbHelper.database;
      await db.rawUpdate('$sql', ${element.parameters.map((p) => p.name).toList()});
    }
    ''';
  }

  String generateDeleteMethod(MethodElement element, String sql) {
    return '''
    Future<void> ${element.name}(${element.parameters.map((p) => '${p.type} ${p.name}').join(', ')}) async {
      final db = await dbHelper.database;
      await db.rawDelete('$sql', ${element.parameters.map((p) => p.name).toList()});
    }
    ''';
  }
}


And here is the userDao
import 'package:tao_bao/db/user_model.dart';

import 'database_annotations.dart';

@Table('users')
class UserDao {
  @Insert('users')
  Future<void> insertUser(User user) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @Query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?')
  Future<User?> findByUsername(String username) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @Update('UPDATE users SET username = ?, password = ? WHERE uid = ?')
  Future<void> updateUser(User user) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @Delete('DELETE FROM users WHERE uid = ?')
  Future<void> deleteUser(int uid) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }


}

Why can't I successfully generate the user_dao.g.dart file
I am a beginner using Flutter, but I do not want to use an ORM framework similar to Floor. I have tried the Flutter Pub run build_runner build -- delete conflict outputs command and dart run build_runner build
Neither Flutter Pub Get nor others can solve the problem.
How can I do?

Well, in fact, this problem that has been bothering me for a long time, Android Studio has been giving me prompts like this:

[WARNING] Configuring database_generator:database_generator in
target tao_bao:tao_bao but this is not a known Builder

It prompts me to change the items in the builders column to the database generator mentioned in the prompt in build. yaml. The database generator looks like this:
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      database_generator:database_generator:
        enabled: true

builders:
  database_generator:database_generator:
    import: "package:tao_bao/db/database_generator.dart"
    builder_factories: ["databaseBuilder"]
    build_extensions: {".dart": [".g.dart"]}
    auto_apply:  root_package
    build_to: source


Perhaps this helps?
https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/1769
